# Using $xx in array if possible

Tags: php, arrays

Pleas can you help if possible:

```
$xx_array = array(64,65,66,67);
.
.
.
foreach($xx_array AS $xx) {
```

Works perfectly
but what I would like to do is:

```
$yy='5,6,7,8';

$xx_array = array($yy);
.
.
.
foreach($xx_array AS $xx) {
```

When I do this only first number is dealt with!?

The reason why I want it this way because I need same numbers in multiple array-s so I taught to have it in separate php file and just add include so I change only one file if needed!

Comment: Try `$xx_array = explode(",",$yy);`

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql]?  Are you storing delimited strings in a relational database?  [You really shouldn't do that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574).

Comment: Removed the unnecessary tags from this post. Reason; Your question mentions nothing to do with database interaction

Comment: Sorry the reason I included mysql is that the whole script (which is not shown here)is involved in inserting or inputting data in DB!

Comment: @Internetcaffe: Can you be more explicit?  As I said, you *really* shouldn't store delimited strings of this sort in your database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `explode`:

```
$yy='5,6,7,8';
$xx_array = explode(',', $yy);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Wouldn't this create a multi-dimentional array as explode() returns an array and you're putting it inside array()?

Comment: It seems to work as a charm :)
Is there a limit on number of numbers or number of digits (1,100,10000,1000000)

Comment: @Internetcaffe it is only limited by your available memory. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Answer (score 4):

Use explode:

```
$xx_array = explode(',', $yy);
```

Answer (score 4):

`$yy` is set as a string for `5,6,7,8`.. To Get this string you will need to use `explode();` which will turn that string into an array.

```
$xx_array = explode(',', $yy);
```

See the manual:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Example:

```
<?php
$yy = '5,6,7,8';

$xx_array = explode(',', $yy);
print_r($xx_array);
?>
```

The `print_r();` Will Return:

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 [2] => 7 [3] => 8 )
```

Which is what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

Using `explode`:

```
$xx_array = explode(",", $yy);
```

Which automatically breaks apart your string by `","` and creates an array

Comment: Why would the OP use explode in this case? stating that he/she will need to use a function but not giving a reason why? Not a proper constructed answer

Comment: Was in the middle of adding my explanation

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer to your question:

```
$yy='5,6,7,8';

$xx_array = array($yy);

foreach($xx_array AS $xx) {
```

$yy isn't an actual array itself. It's just a string. So $yy needs to become an array.
Yes you can use the explode or you can do this:

```
$yy = array('5', '6', '7', '8');
```

Now $yy is truly an array.

Comment: Allthough `$yy` is not an array, you can use `explode();` to have `string To  Array Conversion`

Comment: what is better array or explode?

Comment: Personal preference I guess in my opinion. If you implode an array then you get the string value like you had with $yy. If you explode the array you get the piece of it.